# Grunt compass not compiling and not responding

Tags: sass, gruntjs, compass, grunt-contrib-compass

It seems that my grunt-contrib-compass is not working as it should,
I'm trying to use:

`grunt compass:dev`

And the output is:

`Running "compass:dev" (compass) task`

But nothing happen at all, and I got no errors neither

On my `Gruntfile.js` I have:

```
compass: {
  dev: {
    options: {
      sassDir: 'src/assets/sass',
      cssDir: 'src/assets/css',
      imagesDir: 'assets/images',
      outputStyle: 'nested',
      environment: 'development',
      force: true
    }
  },
  dist: {
    options: {
      sassDir: 'src/assets/sass',
      cssDir: 'src/assets/css',
      imagesDir: 'assets/images',
      outputStyle: 'compressed',
      noLineComments: true,
      environment: 'production'
    }
  }
}
```

Using:

`grunt compass:dev --verbose`

I got:

```
Running "compass:dev" (compass) task
Verifying property compass.dev exists in config...OK

File: [no files]
Options: sassDir="src/assets/sass/", cssDir="src/assets/css",` imagesDir="assets/images", outputStyle="nested", environment="development",`
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the output when you run the task with the verbose flag (`grunt compass:dev --verbose`)?

Comment: Here's what I got on my output: 

`Running "compass:dev" (compass) task

Verifying property compass.dev exists in config...OK

File: [no files]
Options: sassDir="src/assets/sass/", cssDir="src/assets/css", imagesDir="assets/images", outputStyle="nested", environment="development", force`

Comment: So looks like a path problem - it's not finding any files.

Comment: Yea it seens to be, but I got `.sass` files on `src/assets/sass/`, just checked

Comment: It was ruby version problem, I changed my ruby version to `ruby-2.2.0-preview1`

and now its fine :)

Comment: spent a lot of time on this myself and if you don't want to be on a preview release, downgrading to `ruby-2.1.5` worked (with latest compass + sass gems.)

Answer (score -1):

Got exactly the same problem but for different reasons.

A good troubleshooting is to make sure compass it's running fine alone. You can try this command on your terminal

```
compass compile your_sass_file.scss
```

mine gave a weird error message

```
Interrupt on line ["18"] of /Users/mynamehere/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/compass-rails-2.0.0/lib/compass-rails.rb: 
[...]
```

It turns out compass-rails-2.0.0 needed to be upgraded to make it work

Hope that helps someone

Comment: The OP never indicates that they're using RoR, your answer is unrelated to the problem.